# Is there any way to generate a DB from an EDMX model without all the table names being pluralised?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-5

I forgot to include a DB creation script in my Git repo to bring work home for the weekend. Ha, I thought, how fortunate I can generate a DB DDL from my EDMX model, but the bloody daft thing goes and uses the entity set names for table names, not the entity names. This blows any ambitions I had of homework out of the bloody water.

Is there any trick in the book to avoid this and get my original table names back?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the table name explicitly for each entity if you go into the Entity Designer, select an entity and edit the Entity Set property. Unfortunately, this will also change the name of the collection property on your ObjectContext.

Oddly, when I it only changed the name of the CSDL entity in the EDMX, not the SSDL entity, yet when I generated the script it used the name from the CSDL entity (not the SSDL entity as one would expect). The EF designer is very bizarre.

Ones solution would be to use Code First, where you have explicit control over the mapping through attributes.

Comment: I just regenerated the EDMX from the pluralised DB, and it singularised it again, so my model is the same. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I could suggest a hack for this but i haven't tried it so i don't know the results and it requires a bit of work, with that being said, create a `DbContext` implementation (just a skeleton) with empty model classes to create an exact mockup of your real model then use [Entity Framework Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d) to generate the DDL code for you by clicking on the `DbContext` file (i know it requires a bit of work).